# TimeSplitter: Error in eval(substitute(exit), data, parent.frame()) : object 'Age' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis

I am newcomer in R. I will appreciate if you to solve my question.

this is my code:

```
dat1 <- read.csv("data.csv",header=T)
spl_dat1 <-
     dat1 %>%
     timeSplitter(by = 5,
                  time_var = "Age",
                  event_var = "Alive",
                  event_start_status = "1",
                  time_related_vars = c("Born", "Death"))
```

And this is my database picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBzTO.png)

this is my `dput(head(dat1))`

```
Born = c(1949L,1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L), 
Death = c(1970L, 1954L, 1954L,1954L, 1954L, 1968L), 
Age = c(22, 6, 6, 6, 6, 20), 
Alive = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Type = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
Label = c("AdministrativeOffices", "DepartmentsDSC", "GeneralOffice", 
"InstitutionsDSC", "Ministries", "NationalBureausAMC"), class = "factor"),
GeneralOffice = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Ministries = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
DepartmentsDSC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
AdministrativeOffices = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
NationalBureausAMC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
InstitutionsDSC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Law = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CentralCommitteeoftheCPC", "NationalPeoplesCongress", "NPCStandingCommittee", "StateCouncilMeeting"), class = "factor"),
 NationalPeoplesCongress = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
NPCStandingCommittee = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
 CentralCommitteeoftheCPC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
 StateCouncilMeeting = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
 Function = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("EconomicManagement", "EnforcementSupervision", "GovernmentOffices", "MacroRegulation", "SocialAffairs"), class = "factor")
```

And this is `structure(dat1)`:

```
Name Born Death Age AgeGroup Alive       Type   
1    1949  1970  22        2     0 Ministries                                            
2    1949  1954   6        1     0 Ministries          
3    1949  1954   6        1     0 Ministries   
4    1949  1954   6        1     0 Ministries   
5    1949  1954   6        1     0 Ministries
6    1949  1968  20        2     0 Ministries
7    1949  2018  70        3     1 Ministries
8    1949  2018  70        3     1 Ministries 
9    1949  1959  11        2     0 Ministries 
10   1949  2018  70        3     1 Ministries
11   1949  1952   4        1     0 Ministries
```

But when I ran the code, An error occurred.

> Error in eval(substitute(exit), data, parent.frame()) : 
>     object 'Age' not found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In max(data[[time_var]]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

There is an "Age" column in my database, and it is numerric. I cannot understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.
It is more likely to get a good answer if you provide the data you are working with.
For example, you can post the output of `dput(head(dat1))` into your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and this is part of the output:
"Born = c(1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L), 
Death = c(1970L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1968L), 
Age = c(22, 6, 6, 6, 6, 20), 
Alive = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Type = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .
Label = c("AdministrativeOffices", "DepartmentsDSC", "GeneralOffice", 
"InstitutionsDSC", "Ministries", "NationalBureausAMC"), class = "factor")"

Comment: please edit your question and post this into your question and not as a comment.
Also post the whole output of `dput(head(dat1))` and not just parts of it.

Comment: thank  you for your advice. I've put the results in question.Does it look right?

Comment: your output should start with `structure(`

Comment: @Cettt, I've paste the dat1 structure. Is there any information I need to release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `event_var` variable needs to be factor (or character) class. There's also a problem with the example, because it only has one level for the status variable. If you allow some of the `Alive` vector to be 1's and make it a factor, then no error. This is pretty clearly an omission in the documentation for the `Greg` package. The vignette example makes no mention of the requirement, but doesn't run into an error because the default for `data.frame` is for character values to be made into factors and the examples use character vectors.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(

Born = c(1949L,1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L, 1949L), 
Death = c(1970L, 1954L, 1954L,1954L, 1954L, 1968L), 
Age = c(22, 6, 6, 6, 6, 20), 
Alive = factor( c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), 
Type = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
                 Label = c("AdministrativeOffices", "DepartmentsDSC", "GeneralOffice", 
                           "InstitutionsDSC", "Ministries", "NationalBureausAMC"), class = "factor"),
GeneralOffice = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Ministries = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
DepartmentsDSC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
AdministrativeOffices = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
NationalBureausAMC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
InstitutionsDSC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Law = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CentralCommitteeoftheCPC", "NationalPeoplesCongress", "NPCStandingCommittee", "StateCouncilMeeting"), class = "factor"),
NationalPeoplesCongress = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
NPCStandingCommittee = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
CentralCommitteeoftheCPC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
StateCouncilMeeting = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
Function = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("EconomicManagement", "EnforcementSupervision", "GovernmentOffices", "MacroRegulation", "SocialAffairs"), class = "factor"))

spl_dat1 <-
    dat1 %>%
    timeSplitter(by = 5,
                 time_var = "Age",
                 event_var = "Alive",
                 event_start_status = "1",
                 time_related_vars = c("Born", "Death"))
```

No error. The code only coerces character varaibles to factor with this code:

```
if (is.character(data[[event_var]])) 
    data[[event_var]] <- factor(data[[event_var]])
```

...  but does not perform the needed coercion for numeric or integer classed variables.

Comment: Either factor or character will succeed.